# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when i try to release a NSString that has an address allocated to it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, memory-management

I have a NSString that i try to release.

The problem is that in some cases i get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when i try to release it. The NSString has a address allocated to it (I can see in the bottom page that it has allocated memory at 0xABCDEF).

How can avoid this problem while realeasing when there is something there ?

Comment: Can u give some code snippet .. Bcz this may due to many pbm like u Didnt retain like tat

Comment: check whether u are releasing it twice....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can release an object, but the pointer to it can still have a value. It's just that it's a garbage value (i.e. a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)).

That's why you see a lot of code such as:

```
[myObject release];
myObject nil;
```

which first releases the object and then sets the pointer to `nil`. That way any message sent to it will fail silently (because it's safe to send messages to `nil` objects in Objective-C) rather than crashing, as seems to be happening with your app.

Since you are checking the pointer, I suspect that you are doing something weird with memory management. Don't. Just follow the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and only release the objects you own.

Comment: +1 I usually create a macro, like this: `#define SXRelease(obj) [obj release]; obj = nil`. I have the same for `free()`: `#define SXFree(ptr) free(ptr); ptr = NULL`.

Comment: You have a bug and setting the var to nil is just masking it. Better to enable Malloc Scribble for Development builds and fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

You've likely called `[release]` on an already released string. How are you allocating it? When an object is released, or autoreleased, it is not automatically set to nil (0x0).

`[[NSString alloc] initWithSomething]` requires a release call.

`[NSString stringWithSomething]` does not, as by convention, it is autoreleased.

Comment: Can't find "initWithSomething" in the documentation for NSString. <vbg>